# Only show specific div with anchor

Tags: jquery, html, tags, anchor

First of all, my coding skills are very basic so please bear with me.

I am making a website for an art exhibition which has many people contributing.

I have a page called profiles.html which contains all of the profile of the people who have contributed.

Each profile is contented within a DIV called profiles along with an anchor tag of the persons name.

If people go to the website 
www.example.com/profiles.html
they will see all of the profiles.

However when they go to
www.example.com/profiles.html#example.name
they will only see the profile of that person.

I have looked around the internet to try and find answers but I have not found any.

UPDATE:

A follow up question. Is it possible to show/ load extra content in the profiles.html#examplename that would not be seen in profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

- A wrapper with `class="profile"` around each profile
- And id on each pofile wrapper, matching your hash (like "example.name")

Then I believe you want something like this:

```
// On page load
$(document).ready(function(){

    // React to clicks on anchors
    window.onhashchange = hashChanged;

    // React to directly type urls
    hashChanged();

});

// When the URL hash (#something) changes
function hashChanged() {
    // hide all profiles
    $('.profile').hide();
    // get the current hasj minus '#'
    var profileId = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    // show only the appropriate profile
    $('#' + profileId).show();
}
```

Comment: "example.name", does not work because of the ".", remove it and it works perfectly. Thanks for your quick and quality help.

Comment: A follow up question. 
Is it possible to show/ load extra content in the profiles.html#examplename that would not be seen in profiles.html

Comment: Sure, you can either `.show()` elements hidden from CSS, or use ajax to `.load()` more content. You'd have to do that from the `hashChanged` function.

Comment: Could you show me how this works in a JSfiddle? im a visual learner.
 also, would this work to show different content for different people?

Comment: If you setup a jsfiddle I can take a look and tweak it.

Comment: yes, thats exactly it. Once more question. how would I load content, eg a HTML page, into that div, but only when visible? http://jsfiddle.net/JEUSz/1/

Comment: Simon, use jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. You should be able to figure out where it goes on that fiddle code.

Comment: I used PHP and it works like a charm. However for some reason, which has been persistant, when I go to the page. profiles.html#example-name1 and then I reload the page, it shows me all the profiles again.

Comment: Try adding `window.onhashchange()` at the end of your document.ready handler.