# navigate to anchor tag to load more content than normally shown

Tags: jquery, html

This question is a continuation from this thread: 
[Only show specific div with anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988930/only-show-specific-div-with-anchor)

I have a page called profiles.html

it contains the profiles about 20 people all contained in a class called "profile" and an id of "example-name1","example-name2", "example-name3" etc

Navigating to profiles.html#example-name2 will show only that profile.

Now when navigating to profiles.html#example-name2, I want to load more content like div's which are not displayed in just profiles.html.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to recheck the anchor every second or so. If there is an appropriate anchor text, display the appropriate div.

```
window.setInterval('functionName', 100);
function functionName() {
    var url_pieces = document.location.href.split('#');
    if( document.elementById(url_pieces[1]) )
        document.elementById(url_pieces[1]).style.display='';
}
```

Edit: filled out this rough example more thoroughly in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/La6AZ/

Comment: Would that not be impractical to implement?
Could you give me an example of this as I am new to coding?

Comment: It's not perfect, but I don't think you'll notice any slowness. It's not doing anything crazy.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have amended the 'question' with a link to a thread that I based my code off, it might be of help to you.

Comment: @Simon does my example help?

Comment: I am new to JS, could you implement it in a jsfiddle as im a visual learner?